# MS Word 2010: time increment in table

Tags: vba, ms-word, formula, word-field

I have a Word document with a large timetable in it, n rows with each row relating to an activity during a day. I Have assigned each activity a duration D (in minutes) in one column of the table, and an activity start time T, where T(N+1) = T(N)+D(N):

```
Name      | Time  | Duration
Activity1 | 09:00 | 5
Activity2 | 09:05 | 10
Activity3 | 09:15 | ...
```

I'd like the Time Column to be a series of formulas such that they update the whole table correctly if I change the start time or the duration, add or remove a row.

At the moment I'm exporting the list to excel each time to do the calculation, an I do not want to embed a worksheet because of pressure not to change the table from the document's creator.

Is there a way to do this in word?

Comment: Its not possible to replicate the table (style wise) in excel?

Comment: I assume you are not allowed to link the table in the word document with the excel one, as they are different things as [shown here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx)

Comment: I have, up to now, been copying the table to excel and updating the columns then pasting back in. but often, someone will change a duration  without changing the start time, and the table will end up out of sync, so I wanted something in place in the document to remedy this. Sadly, I cannot embed as the document's creator wants it to remain a word table. Really, the whole document should be a spreadsheet.

Comment: If the data was normal numeric data, you could have used Formula in Word table ... but since its time, it would be hard to do it without VBA

Comment: The times can be dealt with (with a bit of compromise) using Word formulas, but you would need Word VBA or other automation to deal with row addition, because the correct formulas would have to be inserted in every row, unless of course you could insist that the user inserts using an autotext or autocorrect of some sort, the user never touched the table layout, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrt my comment about row insertion, you could do this using the following field codes.

Let's suppose the Time is in column B, the initial time is in B2, and the Durations are just numbers of minutes types in Column C.

Then in B2 you have the following fields. To set the initial time, the user would have to display the fields and modify the time in the { SET s } field. Or you could use an ASK field instead.

```
{ SET s "09:15" }{ SET m { ={ref s \@HH }*60+{ref s \@mm } } }{ SEQ r \r2 \h }{ SET t1 "mod(int((m+SUM(C{ SEQ r \c }:C" }{ SET t2 "))/60),24)*100+mod(m+SUM(C{ SEQ r \c }:C" }{ SET t3 "),60)" }{ref  s }
```

In B3 and below you would need the following fields:

```
{ SET c "{ t1 }{ SEQ r \c }{ t2 }{ SEQ r \c }{ t3 }"  }{ SEQ r \h }{ ={ c } \#00:00 }
```

The time calculation is built up in c and for example in B5 it would be,

```
mod(int(initial_time_in_minutes+SUM(C2:C5))/60),24)*100+mod(initial_time_in_minutes+SUM(C2:C5),60)
```

All the {} are the special field code brace pairs that you can enter in Windows Word using ctrl-F9 and the user would have to select the column and press F9 to re-execute the fields. You can eliminate a lot of the spaces in these fields if you prefer. You may need to avoid using bookmark names that look like cell addresses ("t1" etc.)

Comment: this looks a lot like what I wanted - I'll try to get it working!

Comment: THanks for this! I did not end up doing it this way (I'll write mine below) but this helped enormously. As a newcomer to word formulas, I misread 'All the {} are the special field code brace pairs' and wondered why it kept printing out '{'. Also, Alt+F9 is very useful for displaying all the formulas.

Comment: Looks good - yes, I think people generally glaze over when reading the bit about the ctrl-F9, but I have found that unless you say it in the message, even people who have used fields before sometimes end up typing the keyboard characters at first.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled on a solution much like bibadia's above, without the column referencing:

Fields before the table are:

Set the start hours for the table

```
{ set th {9}  }
```

Set the start minutes for the table

```
{ set tm {15} }
```

Then in each time cell paste the following fields:

Print the time

```
{ ref th \# 00 }:{ ref tm \# 00 }
```

Get the increment from the column to the right and add to the minutes

```
{ set tm { = SUM(RIGHT, { ref tm }) } }
```

Strip off any hours from tm and add to the hours (which does not account for 24 roll over like bibadia's does)

```
{ set th { = SUM ({ ref th }, int({ ref tm }/60)) } }
```

Get the remaining minutes

```
{ set tm { = mod({ref tm, 60}) }}
```